# Obter posição de wxTextCtrl

Tags: lua, wxwidgets

Como faço para obter a posição (x e y) de um `WxTextCtrl`?

Não achei nada a respeito nem na documentação.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o método [`GetPosition()`](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a9f36392b289a1e567e95bee073d6533e) disponível na `wxWindow`. Está na documentação. Você não achou provavelmente porque ainda não entende bem herança de orientação a objeto. Uma classe tem tudo o que foi criado nela mais o que herdou das classes superiores, então tem que olhar a documentação das classes que fazem parte da classe que está usando. É claro que tem documentação que coloca tudo, fica mais fácil mas não é o caso desta biblioteca, então você tem que percorrer a hierarquia.

Comment: Estava procurando apenas na classe wxTextCtrl, sinal que devo estudar mais, rs.